# Check null for list parameter in Dapper

Tags: parameters, dapper

Is there a way to check for null when the parameter type is an IEnumerable? I know Dapper will translate the list parameter into a parametrized query so I'm suspecting that's the reason why the list parameter cannot be checked for null but I was wondering if there's a way to achieve that behaviour.

The idea is to do something like this:

```
select * from Table1 where (@ids IS NULL OR id in @ids)
```

Right now that query throws SqlException with the message: Must declare the scalar variable "@ids".
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `id in @ids` is a pattern that is recognized by dapper and treated as an *expansion* - so depending on the number of items in your input `ids`, this could become one of:

```
(1 = 0) -- empty sequence
(id = @ids_0) -- sequence with 1 element
(id in (@ids_0, @ids_1, ...)) -- sequence with multiple elements
```

Because of this, after the expansion, there *is* no `@ids` parameter / variable - so `@ids IS NULL` is not going to work. As such, I propose the best way to do this *in your case* is simply: don't add that part of the tsql. For example:

```
var sql = new StringBuilder("select * from Table1");
if(ids != null && ids.Any())
{
    sql.Append(" where id in @ids");
}
var data = conn.Query<SomeType>(sb.ToString(), new { ids }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing that. I'm also considering using another parameter (@idsRef) as a flag like: where (@idsRef=0 OR id in @ids).

Comment: I had the same question, went with something like (@idsCount=0 OR id in @ids)

Answer (score 20):

```
where Id in @ids or 0=@listCount
```

and then

```
var data = conn.Query<SomeType>(sb.ToString(), new { ids, listCount=ids.Count }).ToList();
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Clean and elegant !

Comment: This solution worked perfectly in my query and is cleaner than the accepted answer.